# Latin for "death to freedom"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Is "mortem libertatem" correct?
Or "Ad libertatem per mortem"?
Or "Mortem via ad libertatem"?

the idea is that through death freedom arises or guarantees

Answer (score 4):

The English in the title is meaningless, so I'll go with your final sentence:

> **Per mortem libertas.**
>
> Through death there is freedom.

*Per mortem* isn't the most natural idiom here, but [it is attested](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23per+mort).

If death is not only the cause, but the location (metaphorically) where there is freedom (i.e. one becomes free after their own dying), you could also using *in* + the ablative:

> **In morte libertas.**
>
> In death there is freedom.

Cf. phrases like *in vino veritas* ("in wine there is truth") or *nihil boni est in morte* ("there is nothing good in death").

The *est* is optional. It's often dropped in mottoes (like *in vino veritas*), so I'd drop it here, too, if your goal is a motto.

Comment: could we also use just the ablative _morte_ instead of the prepositional phrases _per mortem_/_in morte_?

Comment: @Tristan Yep. I didn't include it because it could be more ambiguous, but it would be a simple ablative of means. You could also use *ex* + ablative, come to think of it. All change the meaning slightly, but the English is also ambiguous enough that any work fine.